# Why is papaparse making incorrect subarrays? Dividing data into [0..99][100] array instead of [0][1]...[100]

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome-devtools

My code

```
parse(files: FileList): void {
        const file: File = files.item(0);
        const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(file);
        reader.onload = e => {
            const csv = reader.result;
            const parsed = this.papaParse.parse(csv, { header: false });
            this.papaParse.parse(csv, {
                complete: (results, file) => {
                    console.log('Parsed', results, file);
                    this.results = results;
                }
            });


        }

    }
```

It outputs like this
[image]

I was expecting the data array to have subarray with the information not another set of arrays.
How do I fix this?

Comment: No, that's just chrome displaying arrays with many elements as groups of hundreths. As you can see, the array length is the expected `101`. Click on the array to expand the properties 0 to 99.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bergi mentioned in a comment, that is just the console's way of displaying large arrays so they don't take up too much space. You can expand the [0-99] bit if you want to look in detail at that section of the array.

If Bergi wants to make his comment an answer, I'll gladly delete mine.

Comment: Aah, okay! Thank you!!